Server error - the server failed to fulfil an apparently valid request
I am working in a project where few APIs requires JWT token and few Access token, but in header they can accept both. so i am both of them. The APIs which requris JWT are working fine but those who require AccessToken are sending me 500 status code. I have double the token they are correct, and these APIs are working fine in postman too.
here is my network file code

class NetworkHelper {
  static const String _baseUrl = TarabutUrls.baseURL;
  static const Duration _timeout = Duration(seconds: 60);

  Dio _dio = Dio();
  String? _cachedToken;

  // Private constructor
  NetworkHelper._() {
    _initializeNetworkHelper();
  }

  // Singleton instance
  static final NetworkHelper _instance = NetworkHelper._();

  // Getter for the singleton instance
  static NetworkHelper get instance => _instance;

  // Initial setup of the NetworkHelper
  Future<void> _initializeNetworkHelper() async {
    _cachedToken = AppData()
        .appModel
        .accessToken; // Fetch and cache the token on initialization
    _configureDio();
  }

  // Configuration of Dio with initial settings
  void _configureDio() {
    
    final BaseOptions options = BaseOptions(
      // baseUrl: _baseUrl,
      responseType: ResponseType.json,
      connectTimeout: _timeout,
      receiveTimeout: _timeout,
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer $_cachedToken',
        'AccessToken': AppData().appModel.cognitoToken.toString(),
      },
    );

    _dio = Dio(options);

    _dio.interceptors.add(
      InterceptorsWrapper(
        onRequest:
            (RequestOptions options, RequestInterceptorHandler handler) async {
              log("COGNITO TOKEN ${AppData().appModel.cognitoToken}");
          // Apply the cached token
          if (_cachedToken?.isEmpty == true || _cachedToken == null) {
            _cachedToken = await getToken();
            _dio.options.headers = {
              'Authorization': 'Bearer $_cachedToken',
              'AccessToken': AppData().appModel.cognitoToken.toString(),
            };
          }
          options.headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer $_cachedToken';
          options.headers['AccessToken'] = AppData().appModel.cognitoToken.toString();
          log("HEADERS ${options.headers}");

          return handler.next(options);
        },
        onError: (DioException e, ErrorInterceptorHandler handler) async {
          if (e.response?.statusCode == 401) {
            // todo: start logout procedure
            _cachedToken = null; // Invalidate token
            await StorageHelper.deleteAccessTokenFromStorage();
          }
          return handler.next(e);
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  // Method to fetch the token
  Future<String> getToken() async {
    return AppData().appModel.accessToken;
  }

  // Methods for network requests
  Future<Response> get(String url,
      {Map<String, dynamic>? queryParameters}) async {
    try {
      final Response response =
          await _dio.get(url, queryParameters: queryParameters);
      return response;
    } catch (e) {
      rethrow;
    }
  }
}


_cachedToken this token is JWT token.
AppData().appModel.cognitoToken.toString() this is AccessToken
log("COGNITO TOKEN ${AppData().appModel.cognitoToken}");
this line print the token too.
i debug the code too, check every value in handlers too, but couldn't find where i am doing wrong. Please help to fix this issue.

This seems more like a question for the API provider than anything to do with flutter. If you provided the endpoints you were trying to call maybe someone could help you. The one thing you said that sticks out though is that you're sending both the authorization and accesstoken headers to all requests - it seems to me that if the APIs require different auth methods you should only be sending the one they specify.
